# numpy array iteration to track maximum number so far

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a simple way of iterating through a two dimensional array to store maximum value obtained so far while traversing along a particular dimension. For example, i have an array:

```
[[2 ,  1,  5],
[-1, -1,  4],
[4, 3,  2],
[2 , 3, 4]]
```

and I would like the following output:

```
[[2 ,  2,  5],
[-1, -1,  4],
[4, 4,  4],
[2 , 3, 4]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy; use [`accumulate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html):

```
>>> numpy.maximum.accumulate(a, axis=1)
array([[ 2,  2,  5],
       [-1, -1,  4],
       [ 4,  4,  4],
       [ 2,  3,  4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If computation time is not an issue, you can do something like:

```
my_new_array = [ [max(my_array[i][:j+1]) for j in range(len(my_array[i]))] for i in range(len(my_array))]
```

However it is really not computation-time efficient. It would probably be much more efficient to do 2 loops.

Comment: Thanks..I will probably go with using loops.